# How to show that $\sqrt{p\over p+1}$ is irrational?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers

I want to prove that $\sqrt{p\over p+1}$ is irrational where $p$ is any prime number.

I have been thinking about this problem for several hours without any progress.

To show that $\sqrt{p\over p+1}$ is irrational, I assume that it is rational. So there are integers $m$ and $n$ (which have no common divisors) such that $\sqrt{p\over p+1}=\frac{m}{n}$. By squaring and rearranging, I get $pn^2=(p+1)m^2$ but I am not sure how to proceed from here. I can say that $(p+1)m^2$ is divisible by $p$ and then I do not know what to do!

Comment: Don't you forget that $p$ cannot divide $p+1$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, so $p \mid m^2$, therefore $p \mid m$.  Similarly, $(p + 1) \mid n^2$.  Then what?  (Just trying to articulate what's going on in the OP's mind...)

Comment: $p$ and $p+1$ are definitely do not have any factors common other than 1 ...Moreover..No two consecutive integers are perfect squares..

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris No "Similarily". Ignore $(p+1)$. Work with $p$ and recognize the steps form the proof that $\sqrt2$ is irrational.

Comment: @Arthur, indeed =)

Comment: @user35508: $0$ and $1$ are perfect squares…

Comment: @ Bernard  I meant consecutive naturals

Comment: @user35508: Don't shoot me, but many mathematicians consider $0$ to be natural as well.

Comment: @Mathematician..Oh yes , they do..But where I was taught ..We used the term Whole numbers to represent ${0}$ + $\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose

$$\sqrt\frac p{p+1}=\frac mn\;,\;\;m,n\in\Bbb Z\;,\;\;\frac mn\;\;\text{ is a reduced fraction} \implies pn^2=m^2(p+1)\implies p\,\mid\,m$$

since clearly $\;p\;$ divides the left side and $\;p+1\;$ cannot be divisible by $\;p\;$, but then

$$\;m=pk\implies m^2=p^2k^2\implies pn^2=m^2(p+1)=p^2k^2(p+1)\implies n^2=pk^2(p+1)$$

and thus **also** $\;p\,\mid n\;$ , contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do not know the truth of some of the results that you used in your proof so I also need to prove them too for myself.

Comment: Should not in your first line $pn=m^2(p+1)$ be $pn^2=m^2(p+1)$?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative proof.

Consider the polynomial $(p+1)X^2-p$. By Eisenstein's criterium this polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Clearly $\sqrt{\frac{p}{p+1}}$ is a root of this polynomial. It follows that the extension degree $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\frac{p}{p+1}}):\mathbb{Q}]=2$. In particular this implies that $\sqrt{\frac{p}{p+1}}\notin \mathbb{Q}$.

Once you understand Eisenstein's criterium and field extensions you'll probably like this method. But it is of course overkill compared to the standard method.